# ASP.Net MVC4 Web API via ExtJs 4 - sometimes returns XML sometimes JSON

Tags: xml, json, extjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Can someone please explain why in the following scenario the "ONEController" returns XML while the "TWOController" returns JSON when requested the same way from ExtJs?

MVC Web API code:

```
public class ONEController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
public class TWOController : ApiController
{
    public thing<string> Get()
    {
        return new thing<string>(new string[] { "value1", "value2" });
    }
}
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
public class thing<T>
{
    public thing(IEnumerable<T> stuff)
    {
        Id = 42;
        data = stuff;
    }
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<T> data { get; set; }
}
```

ExtJs controller:

```
Ext.define('EPSS.controller.Things', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

views: [
    'Thing.Index'
],
stores: [
    'ONEs',
    'TWOs'
],

init: function () {
    console.log('controller init');
    this.control({
        'container > ThingIndex': {
            render: this.onPanelRendered
        }
    });
},

onPanelRendered: function () {
    console.log('index rendered');
    this.getONEsStore().load();
    this.getTWOsStore().load();
}
});
```

The models and stores look like this (very simple):

```
Ext.define('EPSS.store.ONEs', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'EPSS.model.ONE'
});
Ext.define('EPSS.model.ONE', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields: [
    'Id',
    'Details'
],
idProperty: 'Id',

proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: '/api/ONE',
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    }
}
});
```

I don't need to DO anything with this example data yet... I just set up a simple ExtJs index view, call the ExtJs app from the Home Index.cshtml and the controller  fires the stores on render.  In the firebug console "TWO" will present some nice JSON, while "ONE" will respond with XML and an uncaught exception: "Unable to parse the JSON returned by the server..."

Comment: If you make your `thing<t>` class implement `IEnumerable<T>` as appropriate, do you get the correct response type?

Comment: The result is the same.  Honestly though, the "correct response type" for me is JSON.  I am actually wondering why the ONEController returns XML.  It seems to me to be the simpler of the two... and is indeed just the default example dumped in by the Microsoft template.

Comment: Add `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();` in Global.asax. This will force WebAPI to return only JSON responses.